# MongoDB no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, server

I was connecting to my MongoDB database installed on my local pc, everything was working fine i was ble to work with mongodb collections when suddenly my pc shutdowned because of loadshedding. After I turned it on again everything was fine except my Mongo Db connection was refused. This was the message being displayed:

[cmd mongodb connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeBco.png)

I think this is caused by firewall, what else it can be? Please help!

Comment: That is probably due to the mongod process not running.

Comment: Which OS ? Is are you running mongodb

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots. Use formatted text, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266 - apart from that: Your MongoDB is not running!

Comment: First i ran mongod and then mongo. Also when I tried to connect through mongo db compass the connection refused there as well

Comment: Im running windows 10 64 bit. Everything was working fine before my pc shutdowned

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I was able to solve my problem. There was an issue with database path. I don't know why this problem arised because I had worked with this db before my pc went off.
However I was able to resolve this issue:

First locate the directory where your db's are stored. Then in your CLI whichever you are using:

```
<Your mongodb/server/bin directory>: mongod --dbpath "<your db directory>"
```